# RDP over internet for selected clients

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services, rds

The basic idea is simple: allow Remote Desktop connections over the Internet.

However: By default, any client can connect to the RDP host. I'd like to restrict that. (Just so you know, filtering certain IP addresses is not an option here.)

I know, with RDS, the host needs a certificate. Is there a way, the client also needs to have a particular certificate installed to be able to connect? Or is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you looked up RDS Gateway Services yet?? It does what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I'll look it up and keep you posted.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. If I got it right, you basically just authenticate with credentials at the gateway, so still, connecting would be possible from any host.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I don't understand. Are you trying to limit the people who can login to the host? (so UserA has permissions, UserB has not?)

Comment: @marsze Um, no. RDS GW does a fair amount more than that...

Comment: @MichelZ Limit who is allowed to connect, but not on a user basis (username/password etc.) but on a client machine basis.

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible. You cannot limit machines. (other than blocking IP's)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit access to specific machines, the easiest method to do this would be to require those machines to establish a VPN of some sort.

If the client machines are on the Domain you may want to look at DirectAccess  as a solution.